# Python : Recursively iterate through list and sublist and remove certain elements or sublists

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I am begineer in Python. I want to achieve below using a recursive function and using builtin functions in python 2.7.

Input list to function :

```
[['P', 'Q'], [['not', 'P'], 'R'], [['not', 'R'], ['not', 'P']], [['not', 'Q'], 'S', ['not', 'T']], ['T']]
```

As 'S' has no compliment ['not','S'] in list, so remove sublist which contains 'S'

```
[['P', 'Q'], [['not', 'P'], 'R'], [['not', 'R'], ['not', 'P']], ['T']]
```

Now 'Q' in above list and has no compliment ['not','Q'], so remove sublist which contains 'Q'

```
[[['not', 'P'], 'R'], [['not', 'R'], ['not', 'P']], ['T']]
```

Now ['not','P'] in above list and has no compliment 'P', so remove sublist which contains ['not','P']

```
[['T']]
```

As 'T'  has no compliment ['not','T'] in above list, so remove sublist which contains 'T'

```
[]
```

This should be returned back after recursion completes. Can anyone suggest how I can achieve this efficiently.

Thanks

Comment: in 3rd case how `['not','P']` is unique as it iterate 2 time?

Comment: ['not','P'] has no compliment 'P' so it should be removed. Thanks for correction. I edited the question

Comment: Can someone please suggest how to do this?